# Method setSerial(boolean serial) gone in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am working on a code migration project from Liferay 6.2 to Liferay 7.1. In Liferay 6.2 there is a class **BaseBackgroundTaskExecutor** containing a method **setSerial(boolean serial)**. However in Liferay 7.1 the method is gone and I cannot find any replacement for it.

Is anybody here familiar with my issue or Liferay in general and can provide me with some guidance?

Greetings,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing the two branches ([6.2.x](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/backgroundtask/BaseBackgroundTaskExecutor.java) & [7.1.x](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.1.x/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/backgroundtask/BaseBackgroundTaskExecutor.java)), it looks like it has been replaced with `setIsolationLevel(int)`. Its Interface's method `isSerial()` is still there, but its implementation changed:

```java
@Override
public boolean isSerial() {
    if (_isolationLevel == BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_NOT_ISOLATED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could just call `setIsolationLevel(BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_NOT_ISOLATED)` instead of `setSerial(false)`. Since `ISOLATION_LEVEL_NOT_ISOLATED`'s value is `4`, any value but `4` would make `isSerial()` return `true`.
Or, if you really want to, you could also just overwrite the `isSerial()` method and let it either return `true` or `false`.

However, you should take a look at the [`BackgroundTaskLockHelperUtil` implementation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.1.x/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/backgroundtask/BackgroundTaskLockHelperUtil.java). Especially it's method `getLockKey(BackgroundTask)`:

```java
protected static String getLockKey(BackgroundTask backgroundTask) {
    BackgroundTaskExecutor backgroundTaskExecutor =
        BackgroundTaskExecutorRegistryUtil.getBackgroundTaskExecutor(
            backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName());

    String lockKey = StringPool.BLANK;

    if (backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel() ==
            BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CLASS) {

        lockKey = backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName();
    }
    else if (backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel() ==
                BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_COMPANY) {
        lockKey =
            backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName() + StringPool.POUND +
                backgroundTask.getCompanyId();
    }
    else if (backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel() ==
                BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CUSTOM) {
        lockKey = backgroundTaskExecutor.generateLockKey(backgroundTask);
    }
    else if (backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel() ==
                BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_GROUP) {
        lockKey =
            backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName() + StringPool.POUND +
                backgroundTask.getGroupId();
    }
    else if (backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel() ==
                BackgroundTaskConstants.ISOLATION_LEVEL_TASK_NAME) {
        lockKey =
            backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName() + StringPool.POUND +
                backgroundTask.getName();
    }
    else {
        lockKey =
            backgroundTask.getTaskExecutorClassName() + StringPool.POUND +
                backgroundTaskExecutor.getIsolationLevel();
    }

    return lockKey;
}
```

So based on your "Isolation Level", a specific lock will be acquired, so you should first consider if you want to have multiple instances of your BackgroundTaskExecutor run parallel (`isSerial()` should return `false`) or not. If not, think about which Isolation Level fits best and use it.